# Handler при блокировании бота

Tags: python, telebot

Eсть ли хандлер для обработки блокировки бота пользователем (когда пользователь нажимает "Остановить и блокировать")? Использую PyTelegramBotApi.

Answer (score 0):

Из документации:

> My Chat Member Handler
>
> Handle updates of a the bot's member status in a chat
> @bot.my_chat_member_handler() # <- passes a ChatMemberUpdated type
> object to your function

Собственно в случае с приватными чатами с ботом, в ней можно получить только события блокировки и разблокировки бота пользователем.

Comment: @farkon00 , какое еще действие? my_chat_member - это стандартное событие, которое приходит от серверов телеграмм когда кто-то из пользователей в чате с ботом изменяет статус, например блокирует бота и уходит из чата. Это событие просто надо обрабатывать в коде бота.

Answer (score -1):

Надо создать чат, добавить в него бота и включить ему в bot father Allow Groups на включено. Потом создать допустим текстовый файл, в котором id всех пользователей. И раз в несколько секунду выполнять try, в котором пытаетесь переслать сообщение в чатах с id из файла и с message_id 1.

Comment: Нерационально по ресурсам